# Newly created packages only show up after manual refresh

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am creating new packages using the Object Model and C#.
I am creating packages with subpackages recursively, and that works fine. However, my changes don't show up in EA after the script is done working unless I manually refresh the project with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>, after which my created packages show up as intended.

I am updating the newly created package `newPackage.Update();`, aswell as refreshing the packages of the parent package `parentPackage.Packages.Refresh();`.

After recursively creating all the packages I additionally call `Model.Update()`, `Repository.Models.Refresh();`, `Model.Packages.Refresh();` aswell as `Repository.Exit()`.

EA seems to redraw the view, but doesn't show the newly created packages.

Am I missing any call at the end that updates the view?

I'm using this code:

```
eaApplication = new EA.App(); // Create interface to EA
eaRepository = eaApplication.Repository;
eaRepository.EnableUIUpdates = true;
eaRepository.OpenFile(pathToEAPfile) 
EA.Package eaModel = eaRepository.Models.GetAt(0);
EA.Package testModelPackage = (getting it via for loop);
EA.Package newPack = testModelPackage.Packages.AddNew("foopackage", "System.__ComObject");
newPack.Update();
testModelPackage.Packages.Refresh();

eaRepository.RefreshModelView(0);
eaRepository.Exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you call this from an external application. Any EA client does not receive notice of underlying database updates. Only when the user explicitly reads the appropriate parts.

You either need to run the above code inside EA as add-in or refresh manually.

**Answer to initial question:** The following was a reply to the initial vague question. I leave that for reference by others.

---

Call

```
Repository.RefreshModelView(0)
```

to reload the whole view from root on. Or pass the PackageId of the package you want to refresh.

N.B. All your additional calls are superfluous. Call `Update()` only for objects that have changed. The `Refresh()` calls are only needed if you traverse a changed collection afterwards (after addition or deletion of objects).

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. However, that still doesn't do the trick. I also tried to pass the individual package IDs for all newly created packages without success.

Comment: You need to pass the parent package. That will cascade down. Try with the `0` first to see it refreshes the whole view.

Comment: What is your EA release? I just tested and the packages appears instantly (without refresh). Pls. also post your code.

Comment: I'm using release 12.1.1227 (Build 1227). Minimal example: `eaApplication = new EA.App(); // Create interface to EA

eaRepository = eaApplication.Repository;

eaRepository.EnableUIUpdates = true;

eaRepository.OpenFile(pathToEAPfile) 

EA.Package eaModel = eaRepository.Models.GetAt(0);

EA.Package testModelPackage = (getting it via for loop);

EA.Package newPack = testModelPackage.Packages.AddNew("foopackage", "System.__ComObject");

newPack.Update();

testModelPackage.Packages.Refresh();


eaRepository.RefreshModelView(0);

eaRepository.Exit();`

Comment: Sorry, but I can't format it any better in the comments, here's a pastebin link (Gonna leave it there anyway in case anyone in the future needs it and the pastebin goes down): http://pastebin.com/rCXVTKxK

Comment: The 2nd parameter to `AddNew` is not used and you should leave it an empty string. But that's not the reason. The final Exit() will actually kill your repos. So no wonder you don't see anything. Remove it.

Comment: That wasn't it, it still behaves exactly the same!

Comment: Pls. explain "how" you use the code. I suspect you call that externally and expect your EA client to refresh?

Comment: Yes, this is using the object model, so it's a separate C# program running on it's own while EA is running, and not an Add-In if that's your question.